# how display content in listview

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml

I am trying to display groups(#'s) and the students who are in that group. I have two listview boxes on a page(wpf). The first listview box displays the group #. And the second listview box displays the first and lastnames of the group that i have selected in the 1st listview. I'm using observableCollection and binding through xaml. Can anybody tell me how I can display the students in the 2nd listview box depending on the group# i have selected in the first listview?

For example:
Listview(group#) box1: contains group numbers 1-20

Listview(names) box2: contains group firstname and lastname

So if i select group number 1(item1) in listview box1, then in listview box2, it should display the first and lastnames that are in that group#

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated. :)

```
       <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,12" x:Name ="listViewGroups" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" DisplayMemberPath="bindMe" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}" Grid.Column="1">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupNumber}" Width="40">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupNumber" Content="#" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupLeader}" Width="120">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupLeader" Content="Group Leader" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding GroupSize}" Width="70">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="GroupSize" Content="Group Size" Click="SortClick" />
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>

            <Label Content="Leader" Height="28" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="lblFirstName" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
            <TextBox Text="{Binding SelectedItem.GroupLeader, ElementName =listViewGroups}" Height="23" Margin="12,31,0,0" Name="txtFirstName" MaxWidth="160" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="160" />
            <Label Content="Group Members" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="14,60,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Column="2" />
            <ListView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="12,80,188,12" x:Name ="listViewGroupMembers" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}"  IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="{x:Null}" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="2">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding path SelectedItem.FirstName, ElementName= listViewGroups}" Width="100">
                            <GridViewColumnHeader Tag="Name" Content="First Name" Click="SortClick" />
                        </GridViewColumn>

     </Listview>
```

Comment: This may help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996728/wpf-listview-databinding-to-observablecollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am Asumming that you have a Object `Group` and an Object `Student`

So your first `ListView` has `ObservableCollection<Groups>` and Each Group has a List of Students `ObservableColection<Student>` so in Xaml You can bind and Write in this way

```
<ListView Name="GroupList" ItemSource={Binding Path=GroupList}>
</ListView>

<ListView Name="StudentList" ItemSource={Binding Path=SelectedItem.StudentList,ElementName=GroupList}>
</ListView>
```

This you help you... ;)

Comment: why selectedItem.StudentList? just curious

Comment: And my Groups class has a list<Student> members in it allready to where all i need is a for loop to get the members. Idk if this would make things diff.

Comment: @TMan SelectedItem.StudentList means Binding engine knows that SelectedItem is of the Type `Group` so you want to tell the Binding engine that you need that Sepcific property of that Object....and for you second comment i never really understood what you are trying to tell..... the above answer should work

Comment: I'm using the listview as a grid view, wouldnt this change how it's binding each column?

Comment: @TMan Binding for ItemSource will not change as selected item will be same ....... but binding for GridView Columns might